# Is it possible to pin the project into folder panel in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

**Updated**: Probably, my question doesn't make sense. Could you please close it?

I am quite new to Sublime Text. I open my project by dragging and dropping my project folder into Sublime Text.

However, when I quit Sublime Text, and reopen it, my project is gone. I need to drag and drop again. Is it possible to pin my project into Sublime Text, so the next time when I open, my project is still there?

Thanks.

Note: I am using Sublime Text 3

Comment: If you use 'open folder' from the file menu does that work ?

Comment: What I want is whenever I open the sublime text 3, my project must be shown automatically. But this idea seems to be meaningless.

Comment: I don't use sublime ATM but if I opened the folder within sublime from file menu it would always be there next time I open sublime

Comment: it's not right by my side

Answer (score 1):

You can save your project on disk: *Project > Save Project As...* When you open your editor next time it should open automatically. If not, go to *Project > Open recent*.

Documentation: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html

Comment: @chipbk10, could you elaborate?

Comment: probably, my question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Set `"hot_exit": true` in preferences

> Exiting the application with `hot_exit` enabled will cause it to close
>   immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
>   be preserved and restored when next starting.
>   Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
>   without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
>   alongside the project.